# many-to-many with different number of keys

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, composite-key

I use NHibernate with mapping in the HBMs

I have `Table1` like this

```
ID int(PK)
Category int(PK)
authorID int(PK)
```

And another `table2` like this

```
A_ID int(PK)
Category int(PK)
NAME varcher(100)
PK_ID int
```

And I want data like this :
ALL `Table1` with collection of elements of `table2`.

My question : How I can define relationship many-to-many not by PK.

Pay attention : condition for join `table1.Category=table2.Category AND table1.ID=table2.PK_ID`

May be I have to change many-to-many?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a **One to Many** relationship not **Many to Many**.
There can not be a table2 record with many table1 records.

Your key is a **Composite Key** composited of Category and PK_ID

Have a look here for some sample code:
http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2009/03/19/nhibernate-collection-with-composite-id.aspx

Comment: But number of keys is different. And I need to get records of table1 with collections of table2 records. One-to-many this is opposite direction